# jQuery UI Sortable gives Internal Error 500 in Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, jquery-ui-sortable

I have insert this code in my head:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

This is my script in the blade:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#list-items').sortable({
            update: function(){
                    $.map($(this).find('li'), function(el){
                        var itemID = el.id;
                        var itemIndex = $(el).index();

                    $.ajaxSetup({
                        headers: {
                            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                        }
                    });

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: '/elaborazione_processi/ordinaFasi',
                        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
                        data: {"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}", itemID: itemID, itemIndex: itemIndex},
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(data) { console.log(data); },
                        error : function(err) {
                            console.log('Error!', err)
                        },
                    })
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is my controller:

```
public function ordinaFasi(Request $request){

    try{
        $itemID = $request->itemID;
        $itemIndex = $request->itemIndex;
        FaseProcesso::where('id', $itemID)->update(['posizione' => $itemIndex]);

        Log::info($request->all());
    }
    catch(Exception $exception){
        echo json_encode($exception->getMessage());
    }
}
```

And this is the error in the console:

The error is printed for the number of rows.

This is my route:

```
Auth::routes(); 
Route::get('/elaborazione_processi/ordinaFasi','FasiProcessoController@ordinaFasi');
```

How can resolve this problem? I want order a list of item!

[Error I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VvHm.png)

Console - Network:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2NqO.png)

Laravel.log() error:

```
    Next ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\laragon\www\BancaStatoHR\resources\views\processi\elaborazioneProcessi.blade.php) in C:\laragon\www\BancaStatoHR\storage\framework\views\0b6d347da0d8c0285a6745e0d1c578d3f6675f4e.php:22
Stack trace:
#0 C:\laragon\www\BancaStatoHR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\Engines\PhpEngine.php(44): Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine->handleViewException(Object(ErrorException), 1)
#1 C:\laragon\www\BancaStatoHR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine.php(59): Illuminate\View\Engines\PhpEngine->evaluatePath('C:\\laragon\\www\\...', Array)
#2 C:\laragon\www\BancaStatoHR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\View.php(137): Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine->get('C:\\laragon\\www\\...', Array)
#3 C:\laragon\www\BancaStatoHR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\View.php(120): Illuminate\View\View->getContents()
#4 C:\laragon\www\BancaStatoHR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\View.php(85): Illuminate\View\View->renderContents()
#5 C:\laragon\www\BancaStatoHR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Response.php(38): Illuminate\View\View->render()
#6 C:\laragon\www\BancaStatoHR\vendor\symfony\http-foundation\Response.php(201): Illuminate\Http\Response->setContent(Object(Illuminate\View\View))
#7 C:\laragon\www\BancaStatoHR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(615): Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response->__construct(Object(Illuminate\View\View))
#8 C:\laragon\www\BancaStatoHR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(572): Illuminate\Routing\Router->prepareResponse(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Illuminate\View\View))
#9 C:\laragon\www\BancaStatoHR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#10 C:\laragon\www\BancaStatoHR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings.php(41): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#11 C:\laragon\www\BancaStatoHR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#12 C:\laragon\www\BancaStatoHR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#13 C:\laragon\www\BancaStatoHR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php(65): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#14 C:\laragon\www\BancaStatoHR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#15 C:\laragon\www\BancaStatoHR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#16 C:\laragon\www\BancaStatoHR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#17 C:\laragon\www\BancaStatoHR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#18 C:\laragon\www\BancaStatoHR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#19 C:\laragon\www\BancaStatoHR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession.php(64): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#20 C:\laragon\www\BancaStatoHR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#21 C:\laragon\www\BancaStatoHR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#22 C:\laragon\www\BancaStatoHR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#23 C:\laragon\www\BancaStatoHR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#24 C:\laragon\www\BancaStatoHR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#25 C:\laragon\www\BancaStatoHR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies.php(59): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#26 C:\laragon\www\BancaStatoHR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#27 C:\laragon\www\BancaStatoHR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#28 C:\laragon\www\BancaStatoHR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#29 C:\laragon\www\BancaStatoHR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(574): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#30 C:\laragon\www\BancaStatoHR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(533): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#31 C:\laragon\www\BancaStatoHR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(511): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#32 C:\laragon\www\BancaStatoHR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(176): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#33 C:\laragon\www\BancaStatoHR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#34 C:\laragon\www\BancaStatoHR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest.php(30): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#35 C:\laragon\www\BancaStatoHR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#36 C:\laragon\www\BancaStatoHR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#37 C:\laragon\www\BancaStatoHR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest.php(30): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#38 C:\laragon\www\BancaStatoHR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#39 C:\laragon\www\BancaStatoHR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#40 C:\laragon\www\BancaStatoHR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#41 C:\laragon\www\BancaStatoHR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#42 C:\laragon\www\BancaStatoHR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#43 C:\laragon\www\BancaStatoHR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(46): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#44 C:\laragon\www\BancaStatoHR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#45 C:\laragon\www\BancaStatoHR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#46 C:\laragon\www\BancaStatoHR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#47 C:\laragon\www\BancaStatoHR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(151): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#48 C:\laragon\www\BancaStatoHR\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#49 C:\laragon\www\BancaStatoHR\public\index.php(53): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#50 {main}
```

View - ElaborazioneFaseProcessi:

```
@section('content')
<!-- Main content -->
<section class="content container-fluid">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-block">
                    <form method="POST" action="/elaborazione_processi/{{ $processo->id }}/fasi_processo">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {!! Form::label('nome', 'Nome') !!}
                            {!! Form::text('nome', null, ['class' => 'form-control','placeholder'=>'Inserisci qui il nome della fase del processo']) !!}
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {!! Form::label('descrizione', 'Descrizione') !!}
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-block">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <textarea name="descrizione" class="form-control my-editor" placeholder="Inserisci descrizione..."></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Inserisci fase processo</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="comments">
                <ul id="list-items" class="list-group">

                    @php($posizione=1)

                    @foreach ($processo->fasi_processo as $faseProcesso)
                        <li id="{{ $faseProcesso->id }}" class="list-group-item ui-state-default">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <b>{!!($posizione)!!})</b>
                                    <b>{!!($faseProcesso->nome)!!}</b></br>
                                    {!!html_entity_decode($faseProcesso->descrizione)!!}
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    {!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE','route' => ['fasi_processo.destroy', $faseProcesso->id]]) !!}
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">
                                        <i class='fa fa-trash' aria-hidden='true'></i>
                                    </button>
                                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    <a href="/fasi_processo/{{ $faseProcesso->id }}/edit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class='fa fa-edit' aria-hidden='true'></i></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        @php($posizione++)
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<!-- /.content -->

@stop

@section('css')

@stop

@section('js')

<script src="{{ asset('vendor/adminlte/bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js') }}"></script>

<script>
    $( function() {
        $( "#list-items" ).sortable();
        $( "#list-items" ).disableSelection();
    } );
</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#list-items').sortable({
            update: function(){
                $.map($(this).find('li'), function(el){
                    var itemID = el.id;
                    var itemIndex = $(el).index();

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: '/elaborazione_processi/ordinaFasi',
                        data: {itemID: itemID, itemIndex: itemIndex},
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(data) { console.log(data); },
                        error : function(err) {
                            console.log('Error!', err)
                        },
                    })
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<script>
var editor_config = {
    path_absolute : "/",
    selector: "textarea.my-editor",
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
        "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern"
    ],
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image media",
    relative_urls: false,
    file_browser_callback : function(field_name, url, type, win) {
        var x = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth;
        var y = window.innerHeight|| document.documentElement.clientHeight|| document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight;

        var cmsURL = editor_config.path_absolute + 'laravel-filemanager?field_name=' + field_name;
        if (type == 'image') {
            cmsURL = cmsURL + "&type=Images";
        } else {
            cmsURL = cmsURL + "&type=Files";
        }

        tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
            file : cmsURL,
            title : 'Filemanager',
            width : x * 0.8,
            height : y * 0.8,
            resizable : "yes",
            close_previous : "no"
        });
    }
};

tinymce.init(editor_config);

</script>
@stop
```

Model:

FaseProcesso.php

```
protected $table = 'fasi_processo';

public function processo() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Processo::class);
}
```

Processo.php

```
protected $table = 'processi';

public function fasi_processo() {
    return $this->hasMany(\App\FaseProcesso::class);
}
```

Comment: what's your `redirect()->back()`? your are using an ajax request.

Comment: @okante sorry it was just for try a refresh!
I deleted it but don't change nothing, i have the same errors!

Comment: `$itemID = Input::get('itemID');` and `$itemIndex = Input::get('itemIndex')` are not returning array according to your ajax,  so foreach is not adapted.

Comment: @okante sinceraly i don't know wich is the solution. I think that $_GET[''] is the same thing. Whic is the correct syntax?

Comment: remove the foreach loop and do `FaseProcesso::where('id', $itemID)->update(['posizione' => $itemIndex]);`

Comment: @okante i have edit my code but the code error are the same:

Comment: use `try{ your code} catch(\Exception $e){echo json_encode($e);}` and in ajax call `success: function(data) { console.log(data); }` .. post what error you are getting..

Comment: yes, as said let's know about your exception

Comment: @ZaheerAttar
So ... I added the try exception in my controller, and the success function in the ajax call. But I have the same error. I split the error and I came out this in red text:
responseText: <!DOCTYPE html>↵<html>↵    <head>↵        <meta charset="UTF-8" />↵        <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />↵ ecc..
statusText: "Internal Server Error"

This is my first application with laravel and it may be that I made stupid mistakes.
Do you have other tips?

Comment: Yes. Post Full Error what your are getting in your question.. That will only solve your problem.

Comment: @ZaheerAttar I inserted an image with the error that appeared in the console. I hope it's enough.

Comment: hey why are you sending csrf token with get request?

Comment: copy only `responseText` and post it..

Comment: @Mr.Pyramid With POST give me another error:
405 "Method Not Allowed"...it's better use POST?

Comment: I guess there is more than one error.. Post Your `web.php` file

Comment: read the docs bro csrf_field or csrf_token are passed to verify your post request 405 method not allowed here will be thrown if you make a request without csrf_field / csrf_token whereas in get you don't need to pass any token

Comment: are you using authentication? are you authenticated?

Comment: si i use authentication but i'm authenticated @okante

Answer (score 0):

Try this answer, still I'm not sure whether it will work or not post your `web.php`

Remove this line from your `<head>` since `csrf_token()` is only required for post request not for get requests

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

Then make changes as I have made here

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#list-items').sortable({
            update: function(){
         $.map($(this).find('li'), function(el){
             var itemID = el.id;
             var itemIndex = $(el).index();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: '/elaborazione_processi/ordinaFasi',
                        data:  itemID: itemID, itemIndex: itemIndex},
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(data) { console.log(data); },
                        error : function(err) {
                 console.log('Error!', err)
                        },
                    })
                });
     }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Change your controller with this

```
public function ordinaFasi(Request $request){
    try{
        $itemID = $request->itemID;
        $itemIndex = $request->itemIndex;

        FaseProcesso::where('id', $itemID)->update(['posizione' => $itemIndex]);
return redirect()->action(
    'FasiProcessoController@show');
    }
    catch(\Exception $e){
        echo json_encode($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Change in `show` function of controller

```
public function show($id){
     $processo = Processo::find($id); 
     return view('processi.elaborazioneProcessi',['processo'=>$processo]); 
}
```

Check this and if you any problem then shoot here in comment box.

Comment: So i remove all the line:
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />

But don't change nothing...this is my route in web.php:
Route::get('/elaborazione_processi/ordinaFasi','FasiProcessoController@ordinaFasi');

Comment: post your route in your question bro

Comment: the same bro...500 (Internal Server Error)...i read the responsetext error:
I saw this:
index.php - 53 line
 52 $response = $kernel->handle(
 53   $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
 54 );
ValidatePostSize.php - 27 line
19    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
20   {
21      $max = $this->getPostMaxSize();
22        if ($max > 0 && $request->server('CONTENT_LENGTH') > $max) {
24            throw new PostTooLargeException;
26        }
27        return $next($request);
28    }
Pipeline.php
 return $pipe->{$this->method}(...$parameters);

Comment: ok bro I have made changes in your controller please make it in yours and I hope it will work

Comment: @MrPyramid  No way...500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: ok bro @CarmineRuberto please can you show me the preview of the error you are getting because 500 is a common error and may have raised due to many reasons So if you just show me the preview of the error you are getting then it will be helpful

Comment: For preview go to console log > network > and there you will see file that causing this error click on that file you will get the preview of the error

Comment: Bro i have upload the image, but i don't see error in console->network...

Comment: that's all you got in your console?

Comment: ok do one thing I have `$e->getMessage()` in catch so please make that change and then you get error message in console log post that error message

Comment: @MrPyramid  yes...but don't change nothing! I'm so sorry man, but it's incredibile...I can not really figure out what's wrong! Thank's for the support!
There is not a file configuration that can give errors?

Comment: you didn't get message in console?? is there is one more thing called `laravel.log`check that log what you have got but before that clear the al previous logs and then make a request and then show me the error you got in your response after that I can able to solve your issue :)

Comment: @MrPyramid Can you explain me how to implement this laravel.log in my code please?

Comment: 1. go to storage > logs in your project and open laravel.log file and clear whatever you have 
2. then made the request and open the same file after making the request you will get the log of your request

Comment: @MrPyramid ok thank, i share the laravel.log() error above here.

Comment: ok whats in line number 22 in your view put here in comment box

Comment: @MrPyramid 
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);  <- LINE 37

        foreach ($this->cookies->getQueuedCookies() as $cookie) {
            $response->headers->setCookie($cookie);
        }

        return $response;
    }

Comment: in your view file 'elaborazioneProcessi.blade.php

Comment: check this file's line number 22 elaborazioneProcessi.blade.php

Comment: So...in the line 22 there is nothing. Just start a <div class="row">...
But in this page i have one form for insert row in db.
And another part for choose the order of my list.
It's possible that i have conflict with my first form and the Ajax Call?

Comment: @MyPyramid I do that!

Comment: from where you are getting this `$processo` ? post that method too here you have the problem at present

Comment: @MyPyramid
So...i have a relation...process with phase process.
I use two model, look in post.

Comment: bro i need the controller code because you are not either passing the variable to controller or the variable is returning an object

Comment: @MrPyramid
    public function show($id){

        $processo = Processo::find($id);

        return view('processi.elaborazioneProcessi',compact('processo'));
    }

Comment: ok do one thing in your ordinaFasi function log the request variable like this Log::info($request->all()) and  check whether you got id you are passing or not?

Comment: @MrPyramid I don't unterstand why the log error don't work...i dont' see nothing. I put this code in my controller ordinaFasiProcessi: \Log::info('Faseprocessi ID: '.$itemID);

Comment: what did you got.

Comment: @MrPyramid i update my controller, it's correct? Look above the post.
I see the variable in console or laravel.log?

Comment: yeah its correct ok so you have got the values in log ??

Comment: are you redirecting back??

Comment: Sinceraly in ordinaProcessi() i don't put a redirect.
Now i added a redirect with route, but don't work.
The problem is before.

Comment: stay on the same page! i can use back() ?

Comment: depends your requirement. ok so here what I got from you is $processo variable loads the data on the page and then that data is used for update? and after that you are doing nothing? just staying on the same page?

Comment: @MrPyramid FasiProcessoController.php, inside there is the mathod ordinaFasi() that i use for order the list.

Comment: check my answer

Comment: @MrPyramid unfortunately don't work...
I think that the code does not get refresh.

Comment: it's a mission impossible...i'm tired to try to find a solution :S

Comment: no it's not like that it's to be honest one of the easiest and most common error you are working on wrong direction bro it appears when you try to access a property which doesn't exist in the object collection